# Python writing to dictionary times out with large amount of data

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a piece of working code that reads in a pandas column and writes its unique values to a dictionary and map that value to an integer.

The problem is that its too computationally inefficient and always gets killed before it completes. 
I have 165 such columns and 300,000+ rows per column.

example:

```
my pandas dataframe df:
A      B 
cat   lion
dog   tiger
cat   tiger

my output dictionary:
dict['A'] = {'cat':1,'dog',2}
dict['B'] = {'lion':1,'tiger',2}
```

working but extrememly slow code that never makes it to completion:

```
not_num_cols = ['A','B'...]

def replace_str(col_lists):
    my_dict = {}
    for c in col_lists:
        c_unique = df[c].unique()
        my_dict[c] = dict(zip(c_unique,range(len(c_unique))))
        df[c] = df[c].replace(my_dict[c])
    return my_dict

my_dict = replace_str(not_num_cols)
```

in the terminal, the program is automatically killed after running for some time.

How do i make this code more memory efficient?

Comment: Maybe your process is killed by the OOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to categorize (factorize) all non-numeric columns:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   ID    A      B
0  11  cat   lion
1  12  dog  tiger
2  13  cat  tiger

In [16]: for col in not_num_cols:
    ...:     df[col] = pd.factorize(df[col])[0]
    ...:

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   ID  A  B
0  11  0  0
1  12  1  1
2  13  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split into chunks your huge dataframe into smaller ones, for example this method can do it where you can decide what is the chunk size:

```
def splitDataFrameIntoSmaller(df, chunkSize = 10000): 
    listOfDf = list()
    numberChunks = len(df) // chunkSize + 1
    for i in range(numberChunks):
        listOfDf.append(df[i*chunkSize:(i+1)*chunkSize])
    return listOfDf
```

After you have chunks, you can apply the replace_str function on each chunk separately.

Answer (score 0):

The whole `replace_str` function (whose name is not really good to be honest) can be replaced with:

```
import pandas as pd

def replace_str(col):
    return {integer: value_in_df
            for integer, value_in_df in enumerate(df[col].unique(), 1)}

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['cat', 'dog']})

print(replace_str('a'))
#  {1: 'cat', 2: 'dog'}
```